# Complexity of quadratic polynomials isomorphism

Tags: nt.number-theory, polynomials, algorithms, computational-complexity, isomorphism-testing

Two polynomials $f,g$ are isomorphic iff $f(x_1,\ldots x_n)=g(\pi(x_1, \ldots x_n))$ for a permutation $\pi$.

$f,g$ are equivalent if there exists invertible linear transormation
$A$ such that $f(X)=g(A\cdot X)$.

Assume $f,g$ are quadratic.

[Paper](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/research/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/Poly20Equiv.pdf) p.1 claims that equivalence 
of quadratic polynomials is efficient via reduction to sum of squares.

> What is the complexity of isomorphism of quadratic polynomials?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is equivalent to (coloured) graph isomorphism problem.

To see this,
one writes $f(X)=X^\top A_f X$ for $A_f$ a symmetric $n\times n$ matrix. Then $f$ and $g$ are isomorphic if $\pi A_f \pi^\top=A_g$ for a permutation $\pi$. To see it is also only if, suppose $f(X)=g(\pi(X))$, but $A':=\pi A_f \pi^\top\not=A_g=:A$. If $A'_{ii}\neq A_{ii}$ then $f(X_i)\neq g(\pi (X_i))$, a contradiction. If $A'_{ij}\neq A_{ij}$ for $i\neq j$ then $$f(X_i+X_j)-g(\pi(X_i)+\pi(X_j))=2A'_{ij}X_iX_j-2A'_{ij}(\pi(X_i))(\pi(X_j))=2A'_{ij}X_iX_j-2A_{ij}X_iX_j,$$
again a contradiction.   therefore the isomorphism of $f$ and $g$ is equivalent to isomorphism of coloured graphs with adjacency matrices $A_f$ and $A_g$.

Comment: Thanks. What are the colors?

Comment: colours are values of coefficients of $f$ and $g$

Comment: So $f(X)=\sum_{(u,v) \in E(G)}uv$ and the graph is edge colored?

Comment: no, not only edges, but vertices (coefficients of $X_i^2$), too

Comment: But $x_i^2$ is a loop (edge) in the adjacency matrix, or?

Comment: you might think of it as a loop, or just think of vertices being coloured, it does not really matter.